# Django JavaScript tag at the end of a base.html file structure

Tags: javascript, css, django, inheritance

I am developing a website using Django. I am using **Template Inheritance** in order not to repeat code (like navbars for example) in several html child files. Part of the code I do not want to rewrite is that where I embed JavaScript:

```
<script src="whatever"></script>
```

It is also known that this code is better placed at the end of the body in a .html file, since this would avoid locking additional resources from being downloaded more quickly.

So my question is: How should I do to tell my base.html template that the script code shall be **at the end of the body** in every child html file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% block main_body_data %}
    {% endblock %}

    {% block child_js_above_files %} 
    {% endblock %}

    <script src="whatever"></script>

    {% block child_js_below_files %} 
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

child.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}
 Home page
{% endblock %}

{% block main_body_data %}
<h1>main content</h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block child_js_above_files %} 
<script src="whateverabove"></script>
{% endblock %}

{% block child_js_below_files %} 
<script src="whateverbelow"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply make a `base.html` file for the base template.
It should look like,

*base.html*

```
<!Doctype HTML>
...

<head>
 ...
 {% block head %}
 {% endblock head %}

</head>

<body>
 {% block content %}
 {% endblock content %}

 <!-- page specific script tag here -->
 {% block script %}
 {% endblock script %}

 <!-- common script tag for whole site (will be loaded at last) -->
 <script src="whatever"></script>
 ...

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does the tag name need to be repeated in the closing tag?

Answer (score 0):

Create a block at the end of base.html

`{% block js_files %} {% endblock %}`

then overwrite it when it is needed.